# Updating a model by method: SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have method on a model Thing:

```
def method(self, session):
        if self.column_value is None:
            self.column_value = some expensive calculation
            session.add(self)
            session.commit()
            return self.column_value                        
        else:
            return self.column_value
```

So, I can run thing_instance.method and return column_value, calculating if needed. This is how I did it elsewhere, and I'm trying to adapt to doing this w/python.

This is not working as I'd like, I'm getting errors galore....what is a better way?

EDIT:

That method is it in a nutshell. I have thing_instance and call thing_instance.method(). The error I'm getting is:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError: (InterfaceError) Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type
```

Which might be more useful.

I would put more specific code as requested, but that would distract from my question. The issue here is: How exactly do I write a method on sqlalchemy model that calculates and updates the instance column value if the column value is not set? In a pythoinic/sqlalchemic way? What I tried in variations did not work, so I put it aside, asked this question

EDIT2:

It was a column type error.....calculated value was a list, and I need to convert or use PickleType as column. Any pointers still appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide some of the errors galore that you're getting, or provide some more code that better shows how your method is being called?

Comment: I recommend against placing session logic directly in your model classes.  The model classes should simply represent the data and additional methods can do stateless computations on that data.  If you have something else handle sessions and stateful behavior I think you will find your application is more manageable in general.

Comment: I did refactor to pass in the session before moving on, see above. If I would need to do more, point me toward resources for coming to terms with this context. I'm sure where else to put anything; 'expensive calculation' in my context is an imported class that manipulates another field in the the model to create a new field.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are referring to is because integer 0 is an invalid value for the type in question? Also, if the thing_instance is already in the persisted connected state, you do not need to add it to a session! Also, a `session.commit()` most probably is not what you really want here, maybe you meant `session.flush()`?

Comment: I'm still learning...managing the session is new to me. I'm just trying to build interfaces in the model to create, delete, and update instances. The initial error was based in a wrong-ish column-type in the model, not my method.

Comment: the problem is that conceptually the DeclarativeBase classes should not really ever be aware of the session themselves.